# Regex replace the value of a particular pattern (escape double quotes)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bring string of say 2000 characters. I want to search for particular pattern and then replace the part of that pattern.

the string is as follows:

```
data = "additional data \"StartDate\":\"20141101\" additonal data  additional data"
```

Is there a way to change the value 20141101 with some other value say 20121212 that is near to startdate.
I am facing issues with double quotes that are near to the search pattern.

Comment: What is your problem? What problem do you have with the regex?

Comment: the problem is that particular date string can occur multiple times in the actual string, just need to change the value associated with start date.
Note: actual string is not a proper json object, its a random string. json object is part of that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

```
string data = "additional data \"StartDate\":\"20141101\" additonal data  additional data";
```

The one I would use: it uses zero-width assertions to "match" the `"StartDate":"` and the final `"`:

```
string data2 = Regex.Replace(data, "(?<=\"StartDate\":\")([0-9]{8})(?=\")", "xxxxxxxx");
```

The "simple" solution: it matches `\"StartDate\":\"20141101\"` and replaces with `\"StartDate\":\"xxxxxxxx\"`

```
string data3 = Regex.Replace(data, "\"StartDate\":\"[0-9]{8}\"", "\"StartDate\":\"xxxxxxxx\"");
```

Another solution, based on using the special replacers `$1`, `$3`, that are the strings captured in the first and third capture group (the `(...)`)

```
string data4 = Regex.Replace(data, "(\"StartDate\":\")([0-9]{8})(\")", "$1xxxxxxxx$3");
```

Comment: nice one for data2. i needed solution to replace value.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

if the value is always numeric:

```
var data = "additional data \"StartDate\":\"20141101\" additonal data  additional data";
var num = new Regex("StartDate.+?(\\d+)").Match(data).Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(data.Replace(num, "20121212"));
```